# Sign Metamask message and verify with ethereumjs-utils 7.0.10

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

I'm trying without success to get signed Metamask message confirmed with ethereumjs-util in the backend.

Metamask appears to the user, they can sign the message - but when the message is being verified on the back end, I get an error.

```
Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
at assert (project\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:6:21)
    at BN.toNumber (project\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\node_modules\bn.js\lib\bn.js:547:7)
    at Object.exports.bufferToInt (project\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist\bytes.js:148:55)
    at Object.exports.fromRpcSig (project\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist\signature.js:76:21)
    at project\Routes\dashboard.js:21:32 ## will mark this in backend
```

The signature is a 132 character hex, starting with 0x

**Backend code** - Node with Express

```
var ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');

var sig = req.query.sig;
console.log(sig + " length: " + sig.length);

var message = 'data';
const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(message);
const messageHash = ethUtil.hashPersonalMessage(messageBuffer);
const signatureBuffer = Buffer.from(sig);
const sigDecoded = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(signatureBuffer); ### this line is where it throws the Number can only safely store up to 53 bits error

// Recover Address
var recoveredPub = ethUtil.ecrecover(messageHash, sigDecoded.v, sigDecoded.r, sigDecoded.s)
var recoveredAddress = ethUtil.pubToAddress(recoveredPub).toString("hex")
```

**Backend package.json**

```
"ethereumjs-util": "^7.0.10",
"web3": "^1.3.6"
```

**Front end code**

```
import('eth-sig-util');
import('axios');
import(web3);
      
window.ethereum.sendAsync({ id: 1, method: 'personal_sign', params: [ web3.utils.fromUtf8("data"), window.ethereum.selectedAddress] },
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        let sig = result.result;
        axios.get("http://myhost:8000/authenticate/" , { params: { sig }});
    }
)
```

**Front end packages.json**

```
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"web3": "^1.3.6"
```

I've followed all the examples I can find online, including [Sign message with Metamask and verify with ethereumjs-utils](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12033/sign-message-with-metamask-and-verify-with-ethereumjs-utils?newreg=ef131fe07fc9437ca6de66b9efe25bbc) but after working hours on this I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I recently managed this in node js (inside an n8n custom function actually)

```js
const { verifyMessage } = require('@ethersproject/wallet') // https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/utils/signing-key/-%23-utils-verifyMessage

const recoveredAddress = verifyMessage(signedMessage, signature).toLowerCase()
const isSignerMatching = !!(recoveredAddress === expectedAddress.toLowerCase())
```

actually finding out how to import it properly was the most complicated!
as ethers.utils didn't have the promised function!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted finally

Front end should look like this:

```
var message = 'data';
const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(message);
const messageHash = ethUtil.hashPersonalMessage(messageBuffer);
const sigDecoded = ethUtil.fromRpcSig(sig);
```

Comment: i also tried to do this step by step with Buffer conversions, but the below answer is much cleaner.